# кодировка python

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, кодировка, условия

как сделать условие

если файл равен кодировки cp437,  то...

а если файл равен кодировки cp866, то ...

Comment: if coding=="cp437": do this elif coding=="cp866": do that

Comment: cp437 почти совместима с cp866 - можно всё на cp866 обрабатывать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть так:

```
# pip install chardet
from chardet.universaldetector import UniversalDetector

detector = UniversalDetector()
with open('users.txt', 'rb') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        detector.feed(line)
        if detector.done:
            break
    detector.close()

if detector.result['encoding'] == 'cp437':
    #блаблабла
if detector.result['encoding'] == 'cp866':
    #блаблабла
```

модуль  [chardet](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/)